# Why this python code of while loop iis not running?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
i = int(input("write anythinhg-"))
while (i<=99):
  i=input(int("enter again = "))
  print (i)
print ("nice")
```

I have entered this code in python and according to me if I enter a number which is <=99 then the program should ask again until the condition becames true

Comment: Why did you write `int(input(...))` first and then `input(int(...))`?

Comment: I can see that you swapped input and int inside the while loop. 
Secondly do you really mean to 'write anything' ? For example if a person places some non numerical string? 

Could you also tell what do you want to see as output?

Answer (score 1):

You've accidentally flipped the order of `input` and `int` inside your loop:
`i=input(int("enter again = "))`

This is the fixed code:

```py
i = int(input("write anythinhg-"))
while (i<=99):
  i=int(input("enter again = "))
  print (i)
print ("nice")
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I have one more doubt idk why am unable to post it so I am asking u directly from here   Q. Write a program that takes an arbitrary value x, prints TRUE if it is an integer, and it is positive, and it is even (all  3 must be TRUE). or will ask the input again and again until the condition is true ,        I have wrote a code but idk why its not working can u help plz  def z(a):
  while (10):
      if isinstance(a,int):
        print (a,"is a good number")
        break
      else:
        a = input("enter a again = ")

a = input("enter a = ")
z(a)

Comment: isinstance will only check after you cast. you could use str.isdigit to check if a string represents a positive integer, then cast it to int and check if it's even

Answer (score -1):

You inverted int and input. You get the exception because python attempts to convert the string into an integer.

It should be `int(input("number: "))`